# Cannot open tar file

Tags: bash, tar

I have a file called `data`. Although the file doesn't have an extension, I used the `file` bash command to see what type of file it is:

```
$ file data
data: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

Seeing as it is a `tar` file, I try to open it but I get an error:

```
$tar xvf data
tar: data: Not found in archive
```

Comment: Are you sure you haven't specified anything else after `tar xvf data`? It seems `tar` is trying to find the file `data` in the archive, as if you wrote `tar xvf data data`.

Comment: I'm positive. I just entered `tar xvf data`

Comment: Try `tar -xvf data`.

Comment: @piccolo Good for you. Thank you!

Comment: @Roadowl Both the old style UNIX notation `tar xvf data` and the short-style GNU notation `tar -xvf data` are equivalent. The OP most likely wrote something different on the command line.

Comment: What does `type tar` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a hyphen before the xvf.

```
tar -xvf data
```

Else, if you are in another location.

```
tar -xvf /<path to data>/data
```

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. Both the old style UNIX notation `tar xvf data` and the short-style GNU notation `tar -xvf data` are equivalent. The OP most likely wrote something different on the command line.